# i want to Set an alarm at specific time Daily. I have write this code will this work for next day also .Thank you in advance

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I want to set alarm on 10:45 am daily, now in this code problem is that the interval provided in setRepeat() is not working if i put 5*1000 i.e 5 seconds also.Help

```
public void SetAlarm()
{

    BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override public void onReceive( Context context, Intent _ )
        {
            Toast.makeText(context, "hi", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            tex.setText(s[i+1]);
            i++;

            Notification.Builder n  = new Notification.Builder(context)
                    .setContentTitle("Today's Quote")
                    .setContentText(tex.getText())
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_lightbulb_outline_black_24dp)
                    .setContentIntent(PendingIntent.getActivity(context,0,new Intent(""),0))
                    .setSound(uri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION))
                    .setAutoCancel(true);


            NotificationManager notificationManager =
                    (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

            notificationManager.notify(1, n.build());

            context.unregisterReceiver( this ); // this == BroadcastReceiver, not Activity
        }
    };

    this.registerReceiver( receiver, new IntentFilter("com.blah.blah.somemessage") );

    PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast( this, 0, new Intent("com.blah.blah.somemessage"), 0 );
    AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager)(this.getSystemService( Context.ALARM_SERVICE ));
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 10);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 45);
 manager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis()+AlarmManager.INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES,AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pintent);
}
```

1.This will fire an alarm at 11:00 first 
2. Will it fire an alarm everyday.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
manager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alarmTime, 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, pi);
```

instead of

```
manager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis()+AlarmManager.INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES,AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pintent);
```

Comment: I used manager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alarmTime,  5 * 60 * 1000, pi);  to check whether it fires an alarm after 5 minutes .But it didn't.